# Shifting down problem with roadlink

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear, shifting

I have a caadx and recently changed my cassette from 12-28 to 11-36 using a RoadLink setup. I'm using an Ultegra 6600 for my rear derailleur, 11-36 deore cogs and deore 10-speed chain. The cogs,chain and hanger are all brand new.

But my problem is with the 32-t and 36-t gears. Shifting down (small to big), 28→32 and 32→36, I have no problem.

The problems comes when shifting up (big to small) from 36→32 and 32→28. Sometimes when I shift, nothing happens, and when I shift again, the chain will shift twice or sometimes once.

I have no problem shifting up or down on the 11-t through 28-t gears.

Comment: I suspect you're pushing the performance of the rear derailleur beyond its limits. This also depends on how much slack it has to take up so you should tell us about your chainrings as well. I assume when you do this you're in the small ring of two, but is that right? What tooth counts?

Answer (score 3):

First things to check would be cable friction, making sure your b-tension screw is dialed to get the guide pulley as close to the 36 as you can get it without rubbing, and lube pivots. Your cable tension itself could also be on the high side. A directional chain going the wrong direction may also help cause it.

Hanger alignment could contribute too. Just because you put a new hanger on doesn't automatically mean it's perfectly aligned, sad but true.

Answer (score 2):

The 6700 rear derailleur has more capacity and might fix your issue.

OR: You can ditch the roadlink and use a Shimano 9spd MTB SGS RD. They work great with 10spd road shifters.

I used 105 5700 shifters and an XT RD-M761 SGS RD and XT 10spd 11-36 cassette to get up Alpe d'Huez and some other epic climbs in France during summer 2015 and shifting was great!